# angular-bootstrap-lightbox plugin issue in safari browser of Window

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-bootstrap

I have using angular-bootstrap-lightbox in my project . its working fine in all browser.

But issue in safari of window.

Image that display in open modal is get disappear after display.
I have attached screen shot.

Please ignore grammatically mistake.
Thanks.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Km2fW.png)

Comment: Thanks.
I got the solution finally. Issue is Bootstrap lib.
 This  link is update angular-bootstrap-lightbox  version.
"https://github.com/compact/angular-bootstrap-lightbox"